# Can old Canadian paper money still be spent there?

Tags: canada, money

I have some old Canadian paper money that my late father has left us pre 2011, and I am going to Canada soon for a holiday. Can I still use them today? Or do I need to exchange at a local bank for the polymer notes?

Comment: @mlc have things changed in the 7 years since that question? When polymer notes came into UK there were time limits for the validity of paper notes.

Comment: Some of the older paper banknotes have [not been legal tender since 2021](https://www.cheknews.ca/canadians-will-no-longer-be-able-to-use-old-paper-bills-starting-in-2021-bank-of-canada-719284/) but these were mostly commemorative.